# Jquery toggling integer value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When an integer (any integer on page) is clicked on the webpage, this integer must increase by the value of a constant integer. On a second click, the integer must turn back to the original value.

Let's suppose we have an integer

```
<div id="integer-1">25<div>
```

And another integer with a value of 5

```
<div id="const-integer">5</div>
```

When the 5 is clicked, the integer with id `integer-1` should be incremented by 5. On a second click, the integer should be reverted back to its original value of 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each integer has its own value. You would have to click on one of the many variable integers on the page, instead of the constant. This is because we are targeting multiple numbers.

Anyways, we can accomplish this by checking the operation of the button. If it's text says `Add 5`, we will add 5 to the previous number, otherwise we will subtract 5. Here's the code for it.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    
  var integer = +$("#integer").html();
    if ($("button").text() == "Add 5") {
        $("button").text("Subtract 5");
        $("#integer").html(integer + 5);
    }
    else {
        $("button").text("Add 5");
        $("#integer").html(integer - 5);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="integer">25</div>

<button id="my-button">Add 5</button>
```